# Is this relative pronoun correct here?

Tags: relative-pronouns

"And a number of twentieth-century writers have assumed, like Hanslick, that fixed pitches are among the defining features of music. Now it is true that in most of the world’s musical cultures, pitches are not only fixed, but organized into a series of discrete steps. However, this is a generalization about music and not a definition of it, for it is easy to put forward counter-examples. Japanese shakuhachi music and the sanjo music of Korea, for instance, fluctuate constantly around the notional pitches in terms of **which** the music is organized."

Q1. Is the use of "which" correct here?

Q2. If correct, what does "which" refer to? "terms" or "the notional pitches" or something else?

Comment: _Which_ is correct, and refers to _pitches_.

Comment: So it says, "Although both shakuhachi and sanjo music are notionally organized around particular pitches, in practice the music fluctuates constantly around those pitches." (Do you know where I might find this article in English?)

Comment: https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=5DKiUOw519oC&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&dq=Japanese+shakuhachi+music+and+the+sanjo+music+of+Korea,+for+instance,+fluctuate+constantly+around+the+notional+pitches+in+terms+of+which+the+music+is+organized&source=bl&ots=XogpDZ4aSY&sig=ACfU3U2Rzb_vkwSDGj_0oCJhm51Ja9bWEQ&hl=ko&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj3vImtpsXvAhXJGaYKHYeIDpYQ6AEwCHoECAcQAw#v=onepage&q=Japanese%20shakuhachi%20music%20and%20the%20sanjo%20music%20of%20Korea%2C%20for%20instance%2C%20fluctuate%20constantly%20around%20the%20notional%20pitches%20in%20terms%20of%20which%20the%20music%20is%20organized&f=false

Comment: what about this? What does "which" refer to here? "commonsense knowledge" or "weakness"?             "Although commonsense knowledge may have merit, it also has weaknesses, not the least of WHICH is that it often contradicts itself. For example, we hear that people who are similar will like one another (“Birds of a feather flock together”) but also that persons who are dissimilar will like each other (“Opposites attract”)."